# PHP get a defined function's arguments

Tags: php, arrays, directory, arguments

I am building a documentation page for a PHP library. I started with [retrieving an array of defined functions from a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197870/1964113), and it's working brilliantly inside of a directory traversing loop.

Now i'm trying to retrieve the arguments that are defined in that function. In this example...

```
function askQuestion(&$person, $question) {
  if(!$person['nice']){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return 'Go to college';
  }
}
```

I would want to retrieve either this string: `&$person, $question`
or an array of each argument somehow? Preferably, i'd want to know if it is a variable by reference like `&$person`.

I found the [func_get_arg(s)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) documentation but, from what I understand, it's meant to retrieve the arguments of the function that you are calling `func_get_args()` from, and not the actual argument variable names. As far as research goes, i'm not fundamental enough with PHP yet to know what jargon I should be using to find this answer online. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to use a tokenizer to do this.... but if you used docblocks in your code, you could annotate all these functions for phpdocumentor to build your code documentation

Comment: Why, out of interest, are you passing $person by reference?

Comment: I didn't specify; this is a fake function. As it is written, there would be no reason to pass $person by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) class:

```
$refFunc = new ReflectionFunction('askQuestion');

$params = array();
foreach($refFunc->getParameters() as $param){
    $params[] = $param->__toString();
}

print_r($params);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Parameter #0 [ <required> &$person ]
    [1] => Parameter #1 [ <required> $question ]
)
```

Online demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57de9e520d4f0c5049775c4f9efc078723c3ea5a).

Comment: Seriously, PERFECT. Thank you so much!