# How to extract Doc Comments from PHP scripts which are not using classes?

Tags: php

I am aware of PHP ReflectionClass to get doc comments from PHP scripts. Now I have come across these hundreds of old PHP scripts that are not using classes but only simple public functions. If I am right, ReflectionClass cannot be used here? My goal is to extract each doc comments. E.g. `test1.php` contains the following lines:

```
<?php
/**
 * some main comments here
 */
...some php lines here...

/**
 * function comment
 * Blah blah
 */
function foo()
{
 ...some php lines here...
}
...and more functions below each with comments

?>
```

So my desired ouput would be a table like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Filename  | FUNCTION | Comment                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| test1.php |          | some main comments here |
| test1.php | foo()    | function comment        |
|           |          | Blah Blah               |
```

Comment: did you try some doc generators? http://phpdox.de/ or https://phpdoc.org/

Comment: Muescha, thanks. Not yet. I would appreciate if you can hint me further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php)

```
$functions = get_defined_functions();

foreach ($functions['user'] as $function) {

    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($function);

    var_dump($reflection->getName());
    var_dump($reflection->getDocComment());
}
```

The result would be (in case you have only the foo function defined):

```
string(3) "foo"
string(43) "/**
 * function comment
 * Blah blah
 */"
```

Comment: Matei, How or where to specify the file test1.php? In my case, I will have hundreds of them say `test1.php` to `test100.php`. How does ReflectionFunction know which PHP file it's currently working on? Pardon me, there is not much documentation I can google around.

Comment: Matei, also, what about the comment "some main comments here" at the start of `test1.php`?  There are comments similar to this every start of a PHP file.

Comment: I have to mark your answer correct and have to give credits also to Joachim from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197851/function-list-of-php-file.